# How to apply machine learning for streaming data in Apache NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a processor that generates time series data in JSON format. Based on the received data I need to make a forecast using machine learning algorithms on python. Then write the new forecast values ​​to another flow file.

The problem is: when you run such a python script, it must perform many massive preprocessing operations: queries to a database, creating a complex data structure, initializing forecasting models, etc.

If you use ExecuteStreamCommand, then for each flow file the script will be run every time. Is this true?

Can I make in NIFI a python script that starts once and receives the flow files many times, storing the history of previously received data. Or do I need to make an HTTP service that will receive data from NIFI?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. **Build a custom processor**. This is my suggested approach. The code would need to be in Java (or Groovy, which provides a more Python-like experience) but would not have Python dependencies, etc. However, I have seen examples of this approach for ML model application (see [Tim Spann's examples](https://dev.to/tspannhw/easy-deep-learning-in-apache-nifi-with-djl-2d79)) and this is generally very effective. The initialization and individual flowfile trigger logic is cleanly separated, and performance is good.
2. **Use `InvokeScriptedProcessor`**. This will allow you to write the code in Python and [separate the initialization](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2017/06/invokescriptedprocessor-template-faster.html) (pre-processing, DB connections, etc., `onScheduled` in NiFi processor parlance) with the execution phase (`onTrigger`). [Some](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/InvokeScriptedProcessor-in-Python/td-p/105763) [examples](https://github.com/sucitw/python-script-in-NiFi) exist but I have not personally pursued this with Python specifically. You can use Python dependencies but not "native modules" (i.e. compiled C code), as the execution engine is still Jython.
3. **Use `ExecuteStreamCommand`**. Not strongly recommended. As you mention, every invocation would require the preprocessing steps to occur, unless you designed your external application in such a way that it ran a long-lived "server" component and each `ESC` command sent data to it and returned an individual response. I don't know what your existing Python application looks like, but this would likely involve complicated changes. [Tim has another example](https://blog.cloudera.com/integrating-machine-learning-models-into-your-big-data-pipelines-in-real-time-with-no-coding/) using CDSW to host and deploy the model and NiFi to send it data via HTTP to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Custom Processor that can do that. Java is more appropriate. I believe you can do pretty much every with Java you just need to find libraries. Yes, there might be some issues with some initialization and preprocessing that can be handled by all that in the init function of nifi that will allow you preserve the state of certain components.

Link in my use case I had to build a custom processor that could take in images and apply count the number of people in that image. For that, I had to load a deep learning model once in the init method and after through on trigger method, it could be taking the reference of that model every time it processes an image.